# Get rid of [move] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

[move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/move) is often misused; even when it is properly tagged, [move-semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/move-semantics)is more specific.

Can we just get rid of it?

We could replace it with different tags. For example, [animated-movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animated-movement), [scrolling-movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrolling-movement), or [file-movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-movement).

Comment: Only 1,191 questions.  Go for it.

Comment: Can we rename it so less people mistag?

Comment: Well a lot of people use it to tag posts about animation. Maybe we should explicitly state that it is not about physical motion or animation? Or rename to "file-movement"?

Comment: The tag wiki suggests that it is about move-semantics in C++, although I dispute that.  On the first page, I see at least three different contexts in which it is used.

Comment: Exactly... That's the problem.

Comment: Renaming won't fix that.

Comment: burninate as too generic?

Comment: It's now 2,608 questions.  Let's re[move] this tag.