# Why this edit with a single tag change was approved?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

[This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56507128/2) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507128/move-elements-depending-on-index-vanillajs) was approved. The only change was the addition of the [move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/move) tag. Which does not mean motion or actual movement in any aspect of programming. According to the wiki, it means [Move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics). 
 The actual meaning of the tag was [discussed here too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251690/get-rid-of-move-tag) in the comments. Was this edit useful?.

The user has the edit privilege. Does this mean that the user can edit any question with any information without being reviewed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The user has the edit privilege. Does this mean that the user can edit any question with any information without being reviewed?

Yes, it does. Users with at least 2k reputation are not subject to edit reviews, which means the edit was not approved through the review system.

(Adding the [move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/move) tag was, indeed, not useful; I have impro-approved your suggested edit.)

Comment: I see you've added "_with vanilla js_" but the question is already tagged with javascript and they both mean the same thing?

Comment: @weegee Q&As about the sort of libraries and frameworks "vanilla JS" is meant to exclude can still fall under [javascript]. That being so, I don't think adding it to the title is redundant (in contrast to adding just "JavaScript").

Answer (score 1):

The user who edited is beyond 2k, which allows them to edit posts without going through the edit review queue.

Thus their edit will overrule.